# Sorting an Array File I/O

Tags: c++, arrays

I was looking for some help in sorting an Array. I have to do it this way, but I am getting some error messages I am not understanding such as:

1. [WARNING name lookup of 'index' changed .
2. matches this 'char* index[const char*, int] undr ISO standard rules
3. matches this index under old rules
4. invalid types 'int&[char()(const char*, int)] for array subscript
5. at global scope

I have some suspicion of what it is but a little lost of how to fix it. 
The file I am opening is  sentence that reads: Oliver was a Golden Retreiver whose fur was long and golden.

As you can tell I am a complete beginner so any tips will be greatly appreciated Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void swap_values(int& v1, int& v2);
int index_of_smallest(int list[],int start_index, int number_used);
void initialize(int list[]);
void Sort(int list[],int&num);
void characterCount(char ch, int list[]);
void readText(ifstream& intext, char& ch, int list[]);
void totalCount(int list[]);
int main()
{
    int index,letterCount[26];
    char ch;
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    cout<<"This is the text of the file:"<<endl;

    outFile.open("C:/temp/Data_Chapter_7_8.txt");
    if(!outFile)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot open file."<<endl;
    }       

    inFile.open("C:/temp/Data_Chapter_7_8.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
       cout << " Cannot open file." <<endl;
    }
    initialize(letterCount);
    inFile.get(ch);

    while (inFile.get(ch))
    {
        int index;
        readText(inFile,ch,letterCount);
        index++;
    }
    totalCount(letterCount);

    inFile.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void initialize(int list[])
{
    for(int x = 0;x<26;x++)
    list[x] = 0;
}
void characterCount (char ch, int list[])
{
    ch = tolower(ch);
    if(static_cast<int>(ch)>=97&&(static_cast<int>(ch)<=122))
    list[static_cast<int>(ch)-97]++;
}
void readText(ifstream& intext, char& ch, int list[])
{ 
    if (ch != '.')
    {
        characterCount (ch,list);
    }
}
void totalCount(int letterCount[])
{
    for(int x=0;x<26;x++)
        if(letterCount[x]>0)  
            cout<<static_cast<char>(x+97)<<" "<<letterCount[x]<<endl;
}
void Sort(int list[], int number_used)
{
    int index_of_next_smallest;
    for(int index= 0; index<number_used -1; index++)
        index_of_next_smallest = index_of_smallest(list, index,number_used);
     swap_values(list[index],list[index_of_next_smallest]);
}
}
int index_of_smallest(int list[], int start_index, int number_used);
{
    int min = list[start_index];
    index_of_min = start_index;
    for (int index= start_index + 1; index < number_used; index++)
        if (list[index]>min)
        {
            min = list[index];
            index_of_min = index;
        }
    return index_of_min;
 }   
 void swap_values(int& v1, int& v2)
 {
     int temp;
     temp = v1;
     v1 = v2;
     v2 = temp;
 }
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you don't use the same name for two different variables.  This will fix at least half your problems right off the bat.

Comment: ok i have done that, now I am getting an erro of name lookup of index1 changed for new ISO 'for' scoping. And "using obsolete binding and index1"

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Sort` function, change

```
for(int index= 0; index<number_used -1; index++)
```

to

```
int index;
for(index = 0; index < number_used-1; index++)
```

because you need to access `index` after the loop ends.

Comment: Thank you, the program is compiling though is showing a blank screen, any tips on how to debug this?

Comment: @user1705380 try stepping through it with a debugger.